# Feature request "Early Bird" badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Opinions of a new badge "Early Bird"

The badge would be awarded for answering first and having the accepted answer on 20/30 questions.  It would be similar to "Enlightened" (First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes), however upvotes would be substituted for accepted answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So basically **its the OP's who are in charge of dishing out this badge** (only *they* can accept an answers) where as with the `Enlightened` badge it is **a community decision** (up votes from users).  When you look at it in that way I don't think its such a good idea...

The green check mark doesn't really mean anything other than that *the OP clicked the accept button*.  It is a very **subjective indication** of a helpful answer because it is the opinion of only one person - that's why community votes are a much more **accurate** way to define an answer as "bad" or "good", "helpful" or "harmful".

Furthermore this might create some peer pressure on OP's to accept answers simply so that the poster can get one check mark closer to a badge...

Comment: When you put it into context like that, it is a valid point.

Comment: Come on guys - going for another [Enlightened badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=172936) to prove my point ;)

Comment: last upvote was from me, congratz on Enlighted - if my badge was implemented, you would be on track for the Early Bird ;)

Comment: Congratulations for **Enlightened** :)

Comment: And Guru is like enlightened but more so and Populist is for answers that the community thinks are better than the good answer the OP accepted.

Comment: what no mention of Tenacious and Unsung Hero